# Plot 2 plotschape series one above the other at the bottom of the chart

Tags: pine-script

I Would like to plot 2 plotshape series one above the other. If I plot my plotshape series as followed :

```
plotshape(longSlide, style=shape.circle, location=location.bottom,color=color.green,size=size.auto,title="Bullish Slide", display=display.all)
plotshape(shortSlide, style=shape.circle, location=location.bottom,color=color.red,size=size.auto,title="Bearish Slide", display=display.all)
plotshape(longEntries and condLongAO, style=shape.circle, location=location.bottom, color=color.green, size=size.auto, title='Buy', display = display.all)
plotshape(shortEntries and condShortAO, style=shape.circle, location=location.bottom, color=color.red, size=size.auto, title='Sell', display = display.all)
```

Series are plotted one over the other.

Is there a way to vertically shift the first plotshaped series ?

Thanks.

Example of the output, with the series one over the other, series should be displayed one above the other :

[image: plotshape]

Other example with the 2 series, one with location.top, the other with location.bottom. I just need have those 2 series one above the other at the bottom of the chart :

[image: plotshape location top and bottom]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a new line `\n` character followed by a non-printing character (e.g. `U+200E`) to your `text` argument as explained [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-lift-plotshape-text-up).

**Note:** You won't see the `U+200E` here but if you copy and paste the code I share below to your pine editor, you should see it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

plotshape(true, text="1")
plotshape(true, text="2\n‎")
plotshape(true, text="3\n\n‎")
plotshape(true, text="4\n\n\n‎")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks appreciated, but I don't think I can use this to solve my issue (or I don't know how to apply it). I have added a picture to my question, which makes it I guess more clear.

Comment: Is it because you want to shift the shape itself and not the text?

Comment: You can have a look a the new screenshot in my question, and you see that for now I just plot a series with location top and the other with location bottom, both with plotshape. There's no text. I just want to have the two at the bottom of the chart and not one over the other...